# How to get the user at the time of saving in the entity in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a base entity and I am trying to get the user from a custom decorator in the beforeUpdate method but it doesn't seem to work, any idea?

base.entity.ts

```
@BeforeUpdate()
  updateDefaultColumns(@User() user: any) {
    this.updatedOn = new Date();
    if(user){
      this.updatedBy = user.userinfo.preferred_username;
    } else {
     console.log('BeforeUpdate entity User not found')
    }
    this.saveUpdateToChangeLog(user);
  }
```

User.decorator.ts

```
export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will refer to my previous post about custom pipes, and how they are working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59720783/1058115