# Is there a possibility for NestJS to use a different Validation libray?

Tags: validation, nestjs, ajv, class-validator

This is just a general question but I am curious if there is a possibility for NestJS to use a different Validation lirabry since it already could use a different Logging library.

The current library is class-validator.

I am currently building a validator library for personal use for now but am not quite sure how to integrate it into NestJS since it has it own Global config and all the other batteries included for Validation library.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe

Comment: you will need to write your own validation pipe (won't be that hard if you understood `validation.pipe.ts`'s source). That buil-int validation pipe doesn't come to play if you don't load it by yourself btw

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!
So does that mean that as long as I don't call upon `import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';` in main.ts file the built-in validation pipe would not be loaded and a custom one could be used to replace the default one?

Comment: you can do that import statement but if you don't bind the pipe `ValidationPipe` to your nestjs app somehow, it won't do anything. There's no "default" validation system here since you need to tell to Nest what validation mechanism you want to use (if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's absolutely possible to use something other that `class-validator`. I personally like `@deepkit/types` and am working on providing a `ValidationPipe` for it in a package so it can be re-used. But even Nest's docs show using a `JoiValidationPipe` (though that one is per route). In short, if the validator is able to use  reflection (i.e. it's class based) you can create your DTOs and let your custom validation pipe read the metadata and do the validation, if it's schema based, you'll need a pipe per route (possibly per decorator) to ensure the right schema is being picked up. But yeah, it's definitely possible to use something out, that's one of the wonderful things about Nest.

Comment: Thank you!
To add on to the comment, I found this thread to be quite informative.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718680/how-do-i-configure-a-custom-nestjs-pipe

Comment: Hi, is there any libraries to connect depkit/type with nest)?